# eclipse plugin for bluej interface

Tags: java, eclipse, object, plugins, bluej

Is there an Eclipse plugin that allows us to see the classes and objects like BlueJ does ? I find it way more easier to create an object and test its methods in BlueJ than in Eclipse.I am still studying, but do the programers use Bluej in real projects and then import the code in Eclipse, or Bluej is just a program designed for students to understand the basics of java ?

Comment: Bluej is missing a lot of functionality that eclipse has, therefor  it's mainly a teaching tool and not a professional developer. as far as I know there are no plugins for eclipse that visualize packages like bluejay

Comment: I would answer that there is an Eclipse plugin called "Object Aid" that can generate UML class diagrams like BlueJ can, but somebody closed this discussion.  (This is a fact -- not an opinion.)

Comment: There's a NetBeans-BlueJ plugin: http://bluej.org/netbeans/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlueJ is an IDE designed for beginners - it's not a professional level IDE, it's one designed to make the process of learning Java as effective as possible for beginners. It can still be used for more advanced programs and tasks, but most people migrate away to something like Netbeans or Eclipse after they become competent.

Nothing that I know of for Eclipse, but there is a [Netbeans plugin](http://bluej.org/netbeans/) out there. I'm not sure if this works with later versions of Netbeans however, the version quoted there is 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

BlueJ is primarily for beginning Java programming. However, the industry seems to be using Eclipse and NetBeans.